# Value search inside multiple files with results save

Tags: sql, shell, powershell, batch-file, grep

I have a very simple task in theory which in practice is quite tedious and time consuming.

I have in excel a list of values (table names) which i need to search individually in a folder filled with files (~ 4800 files) and even if i find or don't find results i need to record either that the table name was not found or all the file names in which the search string was contained.

We are basically trying to locate all custom development reports that make use of custom tables in our database schema. The report queries are contained outside of the DB in a *.txt file.

I'm pretty sure there probably is a way to do this automatically, but my knowledge of script building is quite limited outside SQL.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the lack of detail - was trying to get a new perspective. I've since used some of the information to run a different type of search for my issue and found a solution which i posted below.

Comment: @Compo - Sorry for the lack of detail - was trying to get a new perspective. I've since used some of the information to run a different type of search for my issue and found a solution which i posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I was trying to get a new perspective on my issue so i tried not to give too many details - but i guess it backfired on me.

But from the answer and comments I realized i was having a brain fart and I managed to run a different search and i found something similar to what i was looking for and for all intents and purposes it does what is needed.

I got the answer from: [StackOverflow Thread 25402636](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402636/batch-script-to-search-multiple-string-in-multiple-files)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "manifest_folder=C:\!Work\!Reports\EMEA\only_reports\*.txt"
set "file_list=C:\!Work\!Reports\EMEA\file_list.txt"
set "outputFile=C:\!Work\!Reports\EMEA\results_file.txt"

    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file_list%") do (
        set "found="
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /l /m /c:"%%a" "%manifest_folder%"') do (
            echo %%a is found in %%~nxb
            set "found=1"
        )
        if not defined found (
            echo %%a is not found
        )
    )) > "%outputFile%"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all files that contain your string:

```
findstr /mic:"table name" > contains_table.txt
```

Then list all files and filter the previously found names:

```
dir /b /a-d * | findstr /vg:contains_table.txt > dont_contain_table.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped in finding the final solution that resulted in what i was looking for, for the most part.